# Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 19 Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to do a bulk insert and receiving the following errors. The last two errors do not give an explanation. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong.

```
Games (Numeric (38), not null
AB (numeric (18), not null

Bulk Insert NYM_Player_Stats
From 'C:\\Users\Robert\Documents\test_input.txt'
With
    (Fieldterminator = ',',
     Rowterminator = '0x0A')
```

Errors:

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character
>   for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 5 (AB).
>
> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character
>   for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 4 (Games).
>
> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character
>   for the specified codepage) for row 3, column 4 (Games).
>
> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character
>   for the specified codepage) for row 4, column 4 (Games).
>
> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character
>   for the specified codepage) for row 5, column 4 (Games).
>
> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character
>   for the specified codepage) for row 6, column 4 (Games).
>
> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character
>   for the specified codepage) for row 7, column 4 (Games).
>
> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character
>   for the specified codepage) for row 8, column 4 (Games).
>
> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character
>   for the specified codepage) for row 9, column 4 (Games).
>
> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character
>   for the specified codepage) for row 10, column 4 (Games).
>
> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character
>   for the specified codepage) for row 11, column 4 (Games).
>
> Msg 4865, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
>   Cannot bulk load because the maximum number of errors (10) was
>   exceeded.
>
> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
>   The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an
>   error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>
> Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 19
>   Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: How about all the other errors except the last 2?

Comment: Below is the input:

Comment: NYM, 2016,  Cecchini, 4, 6, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0.333, 0.429, 0.667, 1.095, 1, 0, 0, 2, SS, 2,
NYM, 2016,   Rivera , 33, 105, 10, 35, 4, 1, 3, 16, 3, 0, 0, 0.333, 0.345, 0.476, 0.821, 1, 0, 4, 8, 2B, 17,

Comment: I am lost on all the errors.

Comment: Can someone tell me what error 7399 & 7330 the last two mean. I will take care of the rest.